# How do you call this formula in math terms? Quotient derivative?

Tags: derivatives

Sorry for that noob question, but I've been searching for ages without finding something...

I've got a series of values $x(n)$. Now to get the derivative I would subtract the current value from the previous: 
$y(n) = x(n) - x(n-1)$.

But how do you call the process of taking the quotient in the same way? 
$y(n) = \frac{x(n)}{x(n-1)}$

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want a name ? and $x(n)-x(n-1)$ is often called $\Delta [x](n)$ the (backward) [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) of order $1$, hence $\frac{x(n)}{x(n-1)} = e^{\Delta [\ln x](n)}$

Comment: Taking $y(n)=x(n)-x(n-1)$ is not the derivative, rather it's the first backward difference.

Comment: ok, so how would you call the quotient? First Backward Quotient? The reason I want to know is I whant to search for it so I can find how this is maybe used

Comment: I don't know if it has a standard name but if it does it's probably not the first backward quotient.

Comment: hmm... ok, that doesn't help sadly

Comment: I would call it "taking successive quotients," but that's probably too vague to get any interesting hits.